# SQL column does not fetching NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has a column with NULL displaying in it for 5 rows. But when I tried to fetch those records with the below query it results in 0 rows fetched. Why is it so.? What else I can try for the same.? I am using SSMS 2012.

`select * from table_name where coumn_name is NULL`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

That would suggest that the column is a string and the value is `'NULL'`, rather than `NULL`.

You can try:

```
where column_name = 'NULL'
```

or:

```
where column_name like '%NULL%'
```

If this is the case, you might want to fix the data:

```
update t
    set column_name = NULL
    where column_name = 'NULL';
```